# Get center of decodedpath google maps

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, center

I've been searching for a while now....
I have a `Polyline`, path comes from `google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath`.

Now I want to center my map around that path, even though I don't know where the path is located.

How do I do that?

My code:

```
decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(mapid);

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: myLatlng,
    mouseWheel:true
});

let poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    paths: decodedPath,
});

poly.setMap(map);
```

Comment: okay i got it...
decodedpath[position].lat()

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept that as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add the point in the decoded path to an empty `google.maps.LatLngBounds` object, then call `map.fitBounds` on that bounds object.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i=0; i<decodedPath.length; i++) {
  bounds.extend(decodedPath[i]);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oufa6n4s/)

**code snippet:**'

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var mapid = "aq|rFttwdQiizCfl}AqcbFfxv@_jfBff}@silAdfdDl`UzrlCmpp@z~eBgq@rrz`@~_dK?rfBstgK~daE~eBbwDulch@";
var id = "map_canvas";

function initialize() {
  decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(mapid);

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: myLatlng,
    mouseWheel: true
  });

  var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    path: decodedPath
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < decodedPath.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(decodedPath[i]);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);


  poly.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```